# How to find which process closed a specifc application on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, virus, virus-removal

My system starting behaving "weirdly" after installing a software on my Windows 8 laptop. I noticed for example some hidden program closes some of the softwares I start like VLC and Task Manager. It also starts some other applications without prompting. So, I would like to know if there's some kind of software showing which process send a "CLOSE" event for example to the Task Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to answer your virus issue here.

You can download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (rename it if needed), run it (elevated) and see if there are any weird named / suspicious programs running. **Suspend** each such program one by one and see if the weird behaviour of applications getting killed stops. If yes, that is the culprit program.